# Rows are not being deleted

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code to select and delete rows form table:

```
    <h1>Deleting Multiple Records using PHP &amp; MySQL</h1>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <?php
```

These are my db connection:

```
  $host = "localhost"; // Host name
 $username = "root"; // Mysql username
 $password = ""; // Mysql password
 $db_name = "project"; // Changed database name
 $tbl_name = "users";
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Here is my html code to retrieve data from database:

```
   <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>           </tr>
            <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Gender</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Experiance</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>User Name</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Password</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>

                <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['fname']; ?></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['lname']; ?>   </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['gend']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['exp']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['uname']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['pwd']; ?>    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:confirm('Are you sure to delete')"></td></tr>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
              for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
           $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$del_id'";
             print $sql;
             $result = mysql_query($sql);}

               if($result){echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";}}
     mysql_close();
    ?>
    </table></form></td></tr></table>
     <p>Record count: <?php echo number_format($count) ?></p>*/
```

I tried many times but it not deleting a single row from table.
just now i changed the code of executing query....please check it and inform me...

Comment: A tip: Always print your SQL query, so you can see how it looks. (e.g. do a `echo $sql`)

Comment: I changed that but not working properly...

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice @Matsemann gave you?

Comment: Have you included the necessary javascript? (without seeing the actual files, it's pretty hard to help)

Comment: uhmmm do you actually run the query after your comment "run the query"? mysql_query($sql);

Comment: When i am trying to print the $sql it not showing anything just displaying sql..... and the javascript for conformation to show the admin deleting the user...

Comment: Yes, but what SQL is it displaying?  Show us.

Comment: just it displaying the query... what i wrote in sql with id=""...

Comment: please help me to find out the solution... just now i changed the post code for delete and checkbox...

Comment: If you're not going to cooperate with us, why do you think we're going to be able to help you?  "just it displaying the query" is obstructing.  Copy / Paste.  It's not that hard.

Comment: you're assigning the same `id` to multiple checkboxes. ID's must be unique across an entire document.

Comment: tell me what i want to do with that id.... and how to do that... Actually i am in the beginner stage.. i know only few things..if you guys are helping i can do things in better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0)
{
     $deleteIds = $_POST['checkbox'];   // it will be an array
     $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id in (" . implode(",", $deleteIds) . ") ";
     // run the query
 }
```

We need to see the actual code trying to "delete".  <s>The usual `mysql_query($sql)` won't work.  You have to use `mysql_exec()` instead of `mysql_query()`.</s>

Update:  Sorry, I was confusing another form of query.  `mysql_query("delete from table where (whatever)")` should work, though it returns true on success or false on failure, not a rowset.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_exec() in C:\xampp\htdocs line no.12

Comment: because there's no such thing as `mysql_exec()`.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean  line 13

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, booleanon line 30

Comment: @Ganesh:  Is there error coming from `mysql_query()` after you have given it a sql "delete" command?  If so, that is expected.  There is nothing to fetch after a delete.

Comment: yeah.. that's what i did i simply replaces the updated one in sql querry..... Is that wrong....

Comment: @Ganesh:  After the `mysql_query()`, the only thing to do with its return value is compare it with TRUE or FALSE.  There is no other information there.  If you want to find out how many rows were affected, you can call `mysql_affected_rows()` if the latter returned TRUE (success).  See the *return value* section of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 3):

What is this query

```
$sql = "DEFRE FROM users WHERE id in (" . implode(",", $deleteIds) . ") ";
```

??

For deleting you should do something like this

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $deleteIds) . ") ";
```

Comment: Why not try a SELECT FROM users WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $deleteIds) . "); to see if anything is actually being selected for deletion?

Comment: if it is not deleteing can you print the value of $_POST['checkbox']; and tell us what it contains

Comment: i tried it but not working .... sql command... i don't know why it was happening..please help me to find out solution....

Comment: Have you tried composing a SQL command in the `mysql` shell or a tool that allows that sort of thing? Once you've got a working solution, then you convert it to code. "Not working" is not a helpful diagnosis, either. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Ganesh can you tell the value of $_POST['checkbox'];

Answer (score 1):

I deleted one line ID from my program and i got the answer and it's working fine.

```
                <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['lname']; ?>   </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['gend']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['phone']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['exp']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['uname']; ?>    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['pwd']; ?>    </td>
                </tr>
               <?php } ?>
                <tr><td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:confirm('Are you sure to delete')"></td></tr>
               <?php

               if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
               $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
            for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
             $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
             //print '$del_id';
             $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'";
          //print $sql;
           $result = mysql_query($sql);}
               }
      if($result){
         echo"successfully deleted";
         }
         mysql_close();
    ?>
    </table></form></td></tr></table>
    <p>Record count: <?php echo number_format($count) ?></p>
```